# read string backwards and terminate at first '/'

Tags: python, path

I want to extract just the file name portion of a path. My code below works, but I'd like to know what the better (pythonic) way of doing this is.

```
filename = ''
    tmppath = '/dir1/dir2/dir3/file.exe'
    for i in reversed(tmppath):
        if i != '/':
            filename += str(i)
        else:
            break
    a = filename[::-1]
    print a
```

Comment: The question is poorly worded, should be "How do I extract the filename from a path."

Comment: What book or tutorial are you using to learn Python?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os.path
path = '/dir1/dir2/dir3/file.exe'
name = os.path.basename(path)
print name
```

Answer (score 4):

you'd be better off using standard library for this:

```
>>> tmppath = '/dir1/dir2/dir3/file.exe'
>>> import os.path
>>> os.path.basename(tmppath)
'file.exe'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [os.path.basename(..)](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) function.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import os
>>> path = '/dir1/dir2/dir3/file.exe'
>>> path.split(os.sep)
['', 'dir1', 'dir2', 'dir3', 'file.exe']
>>> path.split(os.sep)[-1]
'file.exe'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers are correct for your "real underlying question" (path manipulation).  For the question in your title (generalizable to other characters of course), what helps there is the `rsplit` method of strings:

```
>>> s='some/stuff/with/many/slashes'
>>> s.rsplit('/', 1)
['some/stuff/with/many', 'slashes']
>>> s.rsplit('/', 1)[1]
'slashes'
>>>
```